# What is the complexity (\Theta version) of the function $\sum = 3i^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: functions, algorithms

What is the complexity ($\Theta$ version) of the function
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 3i^{\frac 3 2}$$

I think that it is just $\Theta(n^3)$ because the $n^3$ grows faster then the constant or the square root, at least thats what makes intuitive sense in my mind. Is there a way to formally prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3+\frac{6}{5}(n^{\frac{5}{2}}-1)=3+\int_{1}^{n}{3x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}{3i^{\frac{3}{2}}} \leq \int_{1}^{n+1}{3x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx}=\frac{6}{5}((n+1)^{\frac{5}{2}}-1)$$

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{3i^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\Theta(n^{\frac{5}{2}})$.

Comment: So you pick an arbitrary lower and upper bound...

change the integral of that function using these bounds ...

and find Theta based off these bounds?

Do I understand this correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The bounds are not arbitrary. Note that because $3x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is an increasing function of $x$, we have $\int_{i-1}^{i}{3x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx} \leq 3i^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq \int_{i}^{i+1}{3x^{\frac{3}{2}} dx}$. Summing gives the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: The same method can easily be applied for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)}$, where $f(x)$ is a monotonic function of $x$. Intuitively, we guess that the sum has the same complexity as the integral, and this turns out to be true.